# "svn log" to display merge sources like subversion of jetbrains integration?

Tags: svn

[Here is a screenshot showing when show history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI2A.png)

"svn log -g" dosen't work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and describe your problem properly.

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details. It's currently hard to understand what exactly is the problem.